# How to start with developing JavaScript for dynamics crm?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, xrm

I am familiar with Javascript and would like to start developing for dynamic crm.

I downloadi the MS CRM SDK, but got lost there.

1. Is the Javascript syntax for MS CRM indentical as regular JS ?
2. What is the XRM ?
3. I tried to hide existing options from picklist and then show it without a success.

Answer (score 2):

XRM is (Any RelationShip Management). The following link gives more details on XRM Programming. XRM is the framework used to access CRM Page Entities and Fields and perform client custom validations and web service integrations.

This link gives basic details of XRM Programming.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328261.aspx

The following book has easy to understand samples 
ISBN 978-1-78439-415-8,
Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Application Design
By Mahender Pal